# How to remove all related product links from Magento?

Tags: magento, product

I create import script to manage related products and I use code like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$related_data = array();
related_data[$linked_product_id]['position']=1;
$product->setRelatedLinkData($related_data);
$product->save();
```

And I get error like this:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`netztech`.`catalog_product_link`, CONSTRAINT
`FK_CAT_PRD_LNK_LNKED_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID`
FOREIGN KEY (`linked_product_id`)
REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE C)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all related product links from the store, the easist method is something like this:

```
 $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
 $sql = "DELETE FROM `catalog_product_link` WHERE `link_type_id`=1";
 $connection->query($sql);
```

Of course check first in your catalog_product_link_type table, what is your link id for related products.Usually it is 1, but good to check first!

Comment: How to do that for one product?

Comment: Just extend the sql like this: DELETE FROM `catalog_product_link` WHERE `link_type_id`=1 AND `product_id` = YOUR_PRODUCT_ID